# Nexus release staging repository solution

Tags: maven, release-management, nexus

I want to implement really simple workflow for our release management:

1. Developers deploy's the build with maven to the **staging** nexus repository
2. QA team access this repository, if they give a green light to the release, they promotes the releases to the **release** nexus repository which can be accessed by the customers

My question is: what is the easiest way to **copy** the content of the certified release from the **staging** repository to the **release** repository? Is there any nexus-copy, migrate, push, ... etc commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that directly in Nexus. It has built-in support for that. **But** you'll need Nexus Pro.

Comment: Nexus Pro staging suite http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/staging.html

Comment: You can't without implementing your own solution.

Comment: Staging promote does more than simply copying artifacts, you also have to worry about getting indexes updated, metadata merged and rehashed etc. It's probably cheaper just to get the tool than to build it yourself.

Comment: Brian, absolutely. Folks are always so cheap. They want great features w/o paying for it.

Comment: ok, i know that nexus pro is a great tool, and i really would like to pay that, but we are not able use that for this project.

Comment: What are the limitations? If you are OSS then use Sonatype's OSS instance. It is free.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but here are my 0.02 that might still be valid for people arriving that late here :)

- If you are doing CI, you will end up needing [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)...
- Then, check out the [Artifact Promotion plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactPromotionPlugin), that basically simulates the promotion of Nexus Pro on Nexus OSS. Of course, it's a workaround, but work.. around. :)